# Apache POI HSSF Streaming

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is there someway to use or implement XLS streaming like their new SXSSF streaming API?
I need to deal with huge XLS and XLSX Spreadsheets, but since their HSSF does not have any streaming available I always have heap space problems (comming to 1GB and errors).

Does anyone have any suggestions with POI?

Comment: Streaming read or streaming write? Only HSSF already supports [streaming read for .xls files](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api)

Comment: @Gagravarr I need streaming write.

Comment: You're going to be out of luck then... The .xls file format has lots of back-and-forth references in it, so you can't easily write it in one go. With .xlsx, the format is split into parts, so you can stream one part while leaving the small bit with lots of references open. XLS doesn't support that.

Comment: @Gagravarr If I am not wrong, JExcel API can stream write for xls, I was just wondering why POI couldn't.

Comment: I don't think it does either - the format just isn't really set up for that, it has too many back-and-forward references.

Comment: @mrcaramori: Do you have a demo that proves that [JExcel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) supports stream writing to XLS? From what I see in the project's [demo](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.12/jxl/demo/Write.java?av=f#102) and source code of [`WritableWorkbookImpl#write()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl/2.6.12/jxl/write/biff/WritableWorkbookImpl.java#WritableWorkbookImpl.write%28%29), all writing occurs in one go.

Comment: @dma_k I am sorry but I don't any samples and I don't intend to do anything with xls/xlsx so soon.

Comment: @mrcaramori: I wanted to say with my comment that JExcel API is not better than POI in that respect (from what I saw from source code). POI can stream cell data, but fails with regions, hyperlinks, comments (see [bug#60416](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60416)).