# OutOfMemoryException while importing .xlsx file in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I am trying to import an .xlsx file in 2 ways:

1) If I run from eclipse and if I import, I am able to import successfully

2) If I make a .jar file of my product and run as a stand alone application without using eclipse, I am getting an OutOfMemoryException and hence fails to import

My file size is around 3mb and I have used poi 3.9, poi-ooxml-3.9, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9, dom4j and xmlbeans as external jars.

I have even tried arguments such as -Xmx1g, -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M etc..

Please help me how can I import an xlsx file even from my stand alone application.

Comment: How did you add the memory parameters using your jar?

Comment: xmx1024 (1GB max heap size that is) might not be sufficient, did you try to increase it further?

Comment: And you are sure Eclipse is using the same Java-VM as you do when running the application stand-alone?

Comment: Eclipse is sometimes bad try to restart Eclipse sometimes it solves this error

Comment: which workbook are you using? the sxssfworkbook uses streaming and should be preferred when a huge file is being imported or the heap space is limited. see http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could use the [streaming API (SXSSF)](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/#SXSSF+%28Since+POI+3.8+beta3%29).

> Since 3.8-beta3, POI provides a low-memory footprint SXSSF API built on top of XSSF.
>
> SXSSF is an API-compatible streaming extension of XSSF to be used when
> very large spreadsheets have to be produced, and heap space is
> limited. SXSSF achieves its low memory footprint by limiting access to
> the rows that are within a sliding window, while XSSF gives access to
> all rows in the document. Older rows that are no longer in the window
> become inaccessible, as they are written to the disk.

Comment: But i should be able to read both xls and xlsx files simultaneously.

Comment: @user3152686 With xls files, there's nothing that can be done to reduce memory usage, it will be loaded completely in memory, unlike with .xlsx files where you have a lot more options to control the memory used.

Comment: for xls you are instead [out of luck](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9134830/1183010).