# Apache POI writing XLS(not xlsx) directly to disk/stream to avoid out of memory?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is there any way to create XLS file directly to Stream? I am using Apache POI and i create XLS file by using Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(); But it writing the rows on heap memory.How can i write to Disk/Stream. SXSSF only for writing xlsx file but i need for xls? Any idea?

Comment: This is to some extent a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134830/apache-poi-hssf-streaming - Have you looked at the comments of that Q?

Comment: xlsx is the latest and archive format that you can use any API to read and write.

Comment: Use a `csv` file? Both Excel formats have parts which reference other parts, so can't be written in a purely streaming manner. CSV can

Comment: It would likely be very hard to build something like SXSSF for XLS as its binary format is not suited for streaming at all. So your best options will be to write an .xlsx via SXSSF or to write a simple CSV and do conversion to .xls with some other tool (LibreOffice/OpenOffice has some conversion/automation options) if you really need this old format here.